# Bash- How do I encode multiple files from a folder as base 64. Currently my code can encode one file

Tags: bash, base64, encode, bulk

I would like this to encode all the text or pdf files having in a folder path.

Ex- Files can be like below in a folder

```
ABC.txt
PQR.txt
XYZ.pdf
```

Please suggest how do I encode all these files into base64 format.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in the top level folder that contains your pdf & txt files

```
 find . -type f \( -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec bash -c 'base64 {} > {}.b64' \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)  Please suggest whether above command can be used to convert excel files(.xls or .xlsx) into base64 which are present in same folder.

Comment: This encodes ***all*** files into base64 by treating them as binary.  You won’t be able to use them in excel unless you decode it first